# Notebooks/script don't recognize project package using poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm posting here a problem I'm getting with poetry. I've put it as an bug report in their github, but now I'm not sure if its a bug or something I'm not understanding

I'm trying to use my project package from notebooks or some scripts placed outside of the source code folder. My project structure is the following:

```
├── notebooks
│   └── Untitled.ipynb
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── scripts
│   ├── init.py
│   └── hello.py
├── source
│   ├── init.py
│   └── utils.py
├── tests
│   └── init.py
└── zip_project.py
```

If I run poetry install and try to import anything from source, whether it's from the notebook or from that hello.py script, it can't find the source module. It works if I do poetry run python scripts/hello.py, but it shouldn't be the solution as it would still not work for the notebooks. I use pyenv for python version management, in case it is relevant.

After checking out [this update at poetry's docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add), I've tried to run "poetry add ./source/", but got the following error:

```
TypeError

expected string or bytes-like object

at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/vendor/py3.7/poetry/core/utils/helpers.py:27 in canonicalize_name
23│ canonicalize_regex = re.compile(r"[-]+")
24│
25│
26│ def canonicalize_name(name): # type: (str) -> str
→ 27│ return canonicalize_regex.sub("-", name).lower()
28│
29│
30│ def module_name(name): # type: (str) -> str
31│ return canonicalize_name(name).replace(".", "").replace("-", "")
```

EDIT: I've updated pyproject.toml ([gist](https://gist.github.com/jralfonsog/22cdd5feeb3f7ca7e4ecd3a65edb17bf)) trying to follow finswimmer advice, but I get a "Directory {} does not seem to be a Python package" error every time I run poetry update.

EDIT 2: I've found out that if my package is named after `pyproject.toml` project name, and remove any other reference to it, it gets installed (that is, the standard way by poetry docs). By the way, if I try to add a package with a different name by editing `pyproject.toml` or by the `poetry add "./my_package/"` way, I get the `"Directory {} does not seem to be a Python package"` error. Why does this happen?

Comment: poetry cannot find your package folder and thus cannot install it in editable mode during `poetry install`. See my answer here, about what poetry is expecting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586856/how-can-i-make-my-project-available-in-the-poetry-environment/66594643#66594643

Comment: Hi, @finswimmer, and thanks for your help. By the way, I've tried to follow your answer and poetry documentation, and came up with a "" error. Please, take a look at the updated pyproject.toml at the gist

Comment: Hi again. I've made a new update.