# How can I make my Python package available in the poetry environment?

Tags: python, dependency-management, python-poetry

I want to provide my python package to my project to avoid sys.path. I have my toml file in the same hierarchy as my lib-folder. I want to provide "my_package" as package. I have been using pyenv as a virtual environment all along. It worked in combination with poetry without any problems. However, when I run the `poetry install` command, I get the error: `Directory /Users/<user>/<repo_name>/lib/my_package for my-package does not seem to be a Python package` .

This is the content of my pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
...
packages = [{ include = "my_package", from = "lib" },]

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
...
my-package = { path = "./lib/my_package/", develop = true }
```

This is the folder structure:

```
./lib
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── file1.py
    └── file2.py
pyproject.toml
```

I have already tried all variations, renaming my package, avoiding hyphens and underscores. I have also taken the package out of "lib" once, so it should be recognized directly by poetry as default. All without success. I also followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586856/how-can-i-make-my-project-available-in-the-poetry-environment), unfortunately I did not get the same positive result. My virtual env is activated. I have also completely deleted my toml-file and created a new one.

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to set *your package* as a dependency? You don't want `[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]`, you want `packages =` in `[tool.poetry]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
...
my-package = { path = "./lib/my_package/", develop = true }
```

Your package **isn't a dependency of itself**. It is *the package that is being defined by the `pyproject.toml`*.